# Angular 4: Erro ao executar o HTTP POST em Arquivo JSON: Not Found 404

Tags: json, http, angular

Bom Dia Amigos,

Estou aprendendo Angular, usando a versão 4.4.6 com Angular-Cli e estou tendo problemas ao usar o serviço http post.

Primeiro criei uma pasta data onde armazenei meu arquivo json e adicionei no arquivo angular-cli.json.

.angular-cli.json:
`"assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "data"
      ],`

Em seguida, adicionei o módulo HttpClientModule no arquivo app.module.ts

app.module.ts:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CadastroComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

E por fim, meu componente cadastro.component para executar um http post no meu arquivo json.

cadastro.component.ts:

```
 import { Component, Input, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
 import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

 import { ParametroComponent } from './../parametro/parametro.component';

 @Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'cadastro',
    templateUrl: './cadastro.component.html'
})

@Injectable()
export class CadastroComponent {

    parametro: ParametroComponent = new ParametroComponent();
    http: HttpClient;

    private data_Url = './asset/data/data.json';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    atualizar() {
       event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.parametro);

        this.http.post(this.data_Url, this.parametro).subscribe(() => {
           this.parametro = new ParametroComponent();
                console.log('Parametro Atualizado com sucesso');
            }, erro => {
                console.log(erro);
            });
    }
}
```

parametro.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'parametro',
  templateUrl: './parametro.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parametro.component.css']
})
export class ParametroComponent {

      @Input() legado: string = '';
      @Input() produto: string = '';
      @Input() subproduto: string = '';
      @Input() tpoevento: string = '';
      @Input() familia: string = '';
      @Input() tpocontrato: string = '';
      @Input() descrevento: string = '';
      @Input() cdorigem: string = '';
      @Input() evenprivate: string = '';
      @Input() efeposicao: string = '';
      @Input() efeifinan: string = '';
      @Input() excluirmov: string = '';
      _id: string = '';

  }
```

Por fim, ao executar o navegador (Chrome) retorna o erro POST http://localhost:4200/data/data.json 404 (Not Found)

Não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar a resolver este problema.

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda.

Comment: Crie uma rota para realizar essa operação ... já que a URL está sendo digitada no browser, o angular precisa saber que isso é uma rota ...